# PrimeNg accordion giving ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedErrror: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ui-state-active: undefined'. Current value: 'ui-state-active: true'.
I am using Angular 7.
I am using CLI 7.3.6
I am using primeng 7.1.0
I am using primeicons 1.0.0

I look online but I didn't find any solutions to my problem.

```
          <p-accordion #accordion [multiple]="true" [activeIndex]="openTabs">
        <p-accordionTab *ngFor="let sym of symptomList; let i=index" header="{{sym.symptomName}}">
            <div class="row my-2 ">
              <div class="col-sm-12 pl-3">
              {{sym.symptomDescription}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2 ">
              <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
              {{scores[i]}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2 ">
              <div class="col-sm-7 pl-3">
              <p-slider [(ngModel)]="scores[i]" name="scores-{{i}}" [min]="0" [max]="10" [step]="1"  [style]="{'width':'90%'}"></p-slider>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2 ">
                <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
              <span class="text-left">Mild</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
              <span class="text-left">Moderate</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
              <span class="text-left">Severe</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row my-2 ">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row my-2 ">
                <div class="col-sm-2 pl-3">
                    <label>What did you do to manage? </label>
                </div>         
                <div class="col-sm-3 pl-3">
                    <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="actions[i]"  name="actions-{{i}}" style="width:100%"/>
                </div>
            </div>
         </p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>      
</div>
<div class="row my-2 ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row my-2 ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pl-3">
    <button type="button" class="btnSecondary" (click)="onReturnCalendar()">Cancel</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary {{status == 'Active'? 'visible': 'invisible'}}">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't expect to get the error when using the accordion.

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing your TS code, but it looks like `openTabs` is changed or assigned between first and second change detection cycles in development mode (in production there is only one cycle). So try to move changing / assigning of `openTabs` into `setTimeout()` callback without time, thus moving its execution to the very end of current execution stack. If this is not the case, please share your TS code

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. For this line of code what would it become:  <p-accordion #accordion [multiple]="true" [activeIndex]="openTabs">

Comment: `setTimeout` that I suggested should be in your TS code, not HTML, share your TS code if you need help

Comment: I made the following change and the error disappear but not sure why?    original:

    <p-accordion #accordion [multiple]="true" [activeIndex]="openTabs">

    to new:

    <p-accordion #accordion [multiple]="true" [activeIndex]="openAccordion">